# Avoiding re-computing the same expression in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following code, I use `abs(v - i)` three times on the same line. Is this expression computed three times when the code is run? Is there a way to avoid this without having to complicate the code?

`x = sum(abs(v-i) if s == 1 else int((abs(v-i)*(abs(v-i)+1))/2) for v in list)`

Comment: It is computed either once or twice per term, depending on whether `s == 1` or not. But it's a simple expression; I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: But would there have been a way to do it only once if the expression was more complex?

Comment: Yes: for instance you could put the `int((value*(value+1))/2)` in a function into which you pass `abs(v-i)` as an argument.

Comment: This is today's adventofcode problem, isn't it? :-)

Comment: Consider creating a function and using [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) to store results of complicated computing. This is the easiest solution I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this expression computed three times when the code is run?

No, once or twice for every list value.

> Is there a way to avoid this without having to complicate the code?

Depends on what you consider complicating the code.

You could use the [idiom that even got optimized](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations) in Python 3.9:

```
x = sum(a if s == 1 else int((a*(a+1))/2)
        for v in list_
        for a in [abs(v-i)])
```

Or if your list values are ints, you could use `math.comb`:

```
x = sum(abs(v-i) if s == 1 else comb(abs(v-i)+1, 2) for v in list_)
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer only shows that it's possible to do what you want with a one-liner, but I would still advise to use a longer approach with an explicit if/else + caching the value, or using numpy arrays and masks.

You can use the walrus operator `:=` to store the value as a variable. This line is equivalent to your original code and will only compute `a = abs(v-i)` once per loop instead of 1-2 times:

```
x = sum(a if ((a := abs(v-i)) is not None) and s == 1 else int(a*(a+1)/2) for v in list_)
```

The problem is that the walrus operator can only be used in a `if` check, so we need to add a check that's always true... It really doesn't help reading comprehension.

"Long" approach:

````py
v = np.array(list_)
a = np.abs(v - i)
x = np.sum(a if s == 1 else np.int(a*(a+1)/2))```
````

Comment: @KellyBundy Right. The conditions should be swapped. The one-liner should not be used anyway, it's neither performant nor readable.

Comment: Yeah, even for my version, which is a bit shorter, I felt the need to spread it over three lines. (Then I think it's readable, and performant as well (well, as performant as it gets while still checking `s` for every element instead of what chepner's answer proposes)). For brevity I btw might've used `if [a := abs(v-i)] and s == 1`, or for cuteness I might've used `if ((a := abs(v-i)) is a) and s == 1` :-)

Answer (score 0):

While https://stackoverflow.com/a/70268402/1126841 regarding the assignment operator is correct, this is a case where I really dislike the assignment expression, as you have to hunt for where `a` is actually defined. I would probably ditch `sum` and accumulate the value in a `for` loop instead.

```
x = 0
for v in list_:
    a = abs(v-i)
    if s == 1:
        x += a
    else:
        x += int(a*(a+1)/2)
```

However, since `s` never changes in the loop, I would refactor this into two separate loops chosen by the value of `s`, one of which can use `sum` without difficulty.

```
if s == 1:
    x = sum(abs(v-i) for v in list_)
else:
    x = 0
    for v in list_:
        a = abs(v-i)
        x += int(a*(a+1)/2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just save abs(v-i) to a variable and then substitute in that variable?

I would create a variable called my_calc = abs(v-i) then use that name. This will clean up your code

Comment: I'm looping through a list, so v is not constant. I made a mistake in the question, but I've fixed it now.